# Create Dataframe from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
   Index  Batch    Name
    0        1      Jon
    1    
    2        2      Adam
    3         
    4        3      Voges
    5       
    6        4      Jon
```

I want to create another dataframe from this dataframe clubbing the batch numbers

```
Batch   Name/Batches
1        Jon(1,4)
2        Adam(2)
3        Voges(3)
4        Jon(1,4)
```

How can i do this, should i create a new list or ordereddict from the existing DF and then convert that to another DF or this can be done on the fly.

UPDATE: 
 Edited with Spaces in between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `groupby` + `transform` with a custom function:

```
def stringer(x):
    return '('+', '.join(map(str, x))+')'

df['Name'] += df.groupby('Name')['Batch'].transform(stringer)

print(df)

   Batch       Name
0      1  Jon(1, 4)
1      2    Adam(2)
2      3   Voges(3)
3      4  Jon(1, 4)
```

---

**Update accounting for empty rows**

You can use `numpy.where` in this case:

```
import numpy as np

def stringer(x):
    return '('+', '.join(map(str, map(int, x)))+')'

s = df.dropna(subset=['Name']).groupby('Name')['Batch'].apply(stringer)

df['Name/Batch'] = np.where(df['Name'].notnull(),
                            df['Name'] + df['Name'].map(s),
                            df['Name'])

print(df)

   Index  Batch   Name Name/Batch
0      0    1.0    Jon  Jon(1, 4)
1      1    NaN    NaN        NaN
2      2    2.0   Adam    Adam(2)
3      3    NaN    NaN        NaN
4      4    3.0  Voges   Voges(3)
5      5    NaN    NaN        NaN
6      6    4.0    Jon  Jon(1, 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [33]: df['Name/Batches'] = \
             df['Name'] + '(' + \
             df.groupby('Name')['Batch'].transform(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.cat(sep=',')) \
             + ')'

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
   Batch   Name Name/Batches
0      1    Jon     Jon(1,4)
1      2   Adam      Adam(2)
2      3  Voges     Voges(3)
3      4    Jon     Jon(1,4)
```